# Running multiple instances of the same Firefox profile / removing the need for profiles

Tags: firefox

I work in a secondary school.
I've managed to put Firefox onto our RM network and into a small computer suite to test it out. My version of Firefox has lots of different lockdowns on it and is configured in a way that, hopefully, the kids can't mess around with.

Firefox would be used to carry out a certain set of tests, but to do this, we require the students to all log in as one (RM) user. Unfortunately, because of this, only one person at a time can use Firefox as otherwise the others receive an error simmilar to;
***Firefox is already running. Please close Firefox and try again.***

Followed by another error box stating;
***Your profile is missing or inaccessable.***

It would be great if someone could help me figure out a way that this could be done.

Thanks in advance for any help or recomendations,

Jack

Comment: I don't know of any way, apart from mirroring the profile on each user's machine. If the school owns the machines you can lock down the configuration in each. If they are the students' own laptops, this will be more difficult to control. In either case you can include the required copying in the script executed when they log into the network.

Answer (score 0):

Give these a try:

[How do I create a default profile for all users of a computer in Windows 7](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/901549)

[Customizing Firefox – Default Profiles](https://mike.kaply.com/2012/03/30/customizing-firefox-default-profiles/)

A noob batch script for profile duplication, script assumes a folder `profile.default` in the current directory. On each execution of the script it creates `profile.copy*` and run a new instance of firefox using that copied profile.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set ff="C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
call :setname profile_name
xcopy /S /I profile.default !profile_name! >nul
start "" %ff% -no-remote -profile !profile_name!
exit /b

:setname
set count=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /B profile.*') do ( 
  set /a count=!count!+1
)
set %1=profile.copy!count!
exit /b
```

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of these will work as they're not seperate users on a local machine, rather, one user being shared on a network. This is so that this specific user gets a different configuration.
The second link doesn't work in the later versions of Firefox which is what I need.  
  
Poo.

Comment: I need them all to run one profile, not a multitude. Besides, I can't have it opening up each time asking them which profile they would like to use.   Nor can I have hundreds to duplicate profiles made...

Comment: @JMaddocks you can't really share the same profile folder. each user should have his own browser cookies which by design is stored as cookies.sqlite under each profile folder. profile duplication and new instance can be automated with script.

Comment: Happen to know where I might be able to learn to do to that?

Comment: @JMaddocks See edited answer with a basic script for a start. if you are completely new to scripting i am unable to help. you have to look for tutorial yourself or ask elsewhere. Also this deviates from my original intention, I thought the links would have set you straight but it ends up me doing the research and such. **Final hint**: the `-profile` switch to firefox will create a new profile if pointed to an empty folder. so if default profile is set up right you can do without manually copying profile.